# php: cant get a download prompt for an excel with readfile

Tags: php, excel, header, fopen, readfile

I 've searched all over the site here and many others but cant find a solution for such a well known problem. I cant get a prompt to download the excel file with php's readfile. I 've tried with the fopen,print(fread),fclose combination too, but that doesnt work either.
The request url is https i got a prompt when it was http:

```
 $path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$legit;  
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');  
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'); 
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='file.xls'");                                                       
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(\$path));
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Expires: 0');
 ob_clean();
 readfile($path);
 exit;
  /*   IF ($file = FOPEN($path, 'rb')) {
   WHILE(!FEOF($file) and (CONNECTION_STATUS()==0)) {
     PRINT(FREAD($file, 1024*8));
 FLUSH();
     }
   FCLOSE($file);
    }
  RETURN((CONNECTION_STATUS()==0) and !CONNECTION_ABORTED());
   exit;
       }    */
```

The request,response headers all are shown fine in firebug but no prompt.

My client headers are sent with dojo/request API:

```
  var args={
             headers :{
                        'Content-Type' :'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Accept' :'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
                            },
                            method:'GET',
                            timeout:10000
                        }
   var deferred=request.get(url,args);//the url is https it worked with http
```

Any help to solve this?

Comment: Your browser does not offer download dialogs if you do an AJAX request. That simple it is. I wonder why you even think that it would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request the data using an AJAX request, the response will be returned transparently in the background to the AJAX process. You have to redirect the main URL of the current page to the file download URL in order to provoke a file download process.

Comment: I changed the onclick event handler to location.href=... and it worked but yesterday before i go for an ajax call i had errors for encoding with this handling. I just assumed ajax would work. Thanks anyway.